# Husband to apply Schengen business visa, can he apply for his wife's visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, business-travel, spouses

Pakistani spouse having UAE residence permit, where husband is going to apply for Schengen business visa, has all required documents (invitation from his Swiss company, hotel booking, travel tickets, insurance). Can he apply for his wife visit visa at same time in Swiss VFS? The husband would be sponsor (for his wife, he will show bank statement, travel insurance, return tickets, invitation letter from husband confirming that he will be responsible for all expenses)?

Is this proper way if husband traveling on business visa to Switzerland and wants to take his wife with him? If not, can you please help to guide?

Comment: You can find some information [on the official website](http://www.eda.admin.ch/eda/en/home/reps/asia/vare/cgdub/visadu.html). In principle each applicant must apply him or herself and fingerprints will be taken so you most likely need to make two appointments. If there are language issues and the like, I assume it's not forbidden to go to your wife's appointment with her but you can't generally apply for her (I believe exemptions are possible but I assume it's for very specific reasons like disabilities).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is ok as long as he can submit the required documents (bank statement, employer letter etc.). It's common for people to take their families on their business trips (but on tourists visas). Usually a tourist Schengen visa does not require you to show up at the embassy (personal experience).

Comment: She wouldn't have to show up at the consulate?

Comment: Even if Employer letter only sponsors Husband ? (As some companies don't sponsor families on business trips). What type of Visa would be applied for wife then, visit or tourist visa ? Will VFS accept Husbands sponsor for a wife ?

Comment: She would have to, to enroll her fingerprints.